# Using Wikipedia Python module give me an SSL Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, ssl-certificate, wikipedia-api

When using the python 3 Wikipedia module I get an SSL Certificate error. When is use `set StrictSSL false` the module works but I don't to do that permanently.

I was wondering if there was something I could change,I saw someone using a verify thing but I'm unsure how.

I am also not on a businesses wifi or anything, I think it is something to do with my computer or the actual code?

Here is the code:

`outputs = wikipedia.summary(wikiSearch, sentences=3m)`

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 344, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 843, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 350, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 355, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 853, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1117, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 641, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 399, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='en.wikipedia.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /w/api.php?list=search&srprop=&srlimit=1&limit=1&srsearch=alex&srinfo=suggestion&format=json&action=query (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dave.py", line 42, in <module>
    index()
  File "dave.py", line 25, in index
    outputs = wikipedia.summary(wikiSearch, sentences=3)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wikipedia/util.py", line 28, in __call__
    ret = self._cache[key] = self.fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py", line 231, in summary
    page_info = page(title, auto_suggest=auto_suggest, redirect=redirect)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py", line 270, in page
    results, suggestion = search(title, results=1, suggestion=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wikipedia/util.py", line 28, in __call__
    ret = self._cache[key] = self.fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py", line 103, in search
    raw_results = _wiki_request(search_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py", line 737, in _wiki_request
    r = requests.get(API_URL, params=params, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 668, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 668, in <listcomp>
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 247, in resolve_redirects
    **adapter_kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='en.wikipedia.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /w/api.php?list=search&srprop=&srlimit=1&limit=1&srsearch=alex&srinfo=suggestion&format=json&action=query (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)')))
```

I hope someone can help! :)

Comment: Your hint is `'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate` - what happens if you `curl https://en.wikipedia.org` ?

My first guess is your computer's clock is off.

Comment: i tried the curl thing and it returned no errors and I have looked at my clock and there no problems there :(